# Where can I track the status of features (including in-development) in major browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge, opera

To leverage the latest web technologies in our applications it is good to know the status of features (like when using [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)) and also the roadmap of major web browsers.

I happened to see [this page](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule) which shows the roadmap for Chrome web browser.

Is there something equivalent for other major browsers like Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on?

Answer (score 0):

1. [The MDN repository](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data) "contains compatibility data for Web technologies as displayed on MDN"
2. [Can I use](https://caniuse.com) "provides up-to-date browser support tables" for Web technologies and features
3. [ECMAScript compatibility tables](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) provides status of ECMAScript support like caniuse
4. [HTML5TEST](https://html5test.com/) lets you know how well your browser supports HTML5
5. [WHAT WEB CAN DO TODAY](https://whatwebcando.today/) is something like HTML5TEST
6. [Browser Platform Status Tracker](https://platformstatus.io/) tracks engine features

---

7. Google Chrome [roadmap](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule) and [features](https://www.chromestatus.com/features) (includes in-development etc)
8. Firefox [implementation and standardization roadmap](https://platform-status.mozilla.org/) (seems to [have been abandoned](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/tsc5mi/what_happend_to_the_firefox_platform_status_page/))
   See Firefox [Specification Positions](https://mozilla.github.io/standards-positions/) instead
9. Microsoft Edge [platform status](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/status/)
10. Safari [webKit feature status](https://webkit.org/status/)
11. Opera ([same as chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/features))

---

12. See [Learn how browsers are working together to make it easier to build for the web](https://youtu.be/fGlhRnp5M-g)
13. See [Interop 2022 Dashboard](https://wpt.fyi/interop-2022)

<sub>Note that Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Opera are all [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)#Browsers_based_on_Chromium)-based browsers that use [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) browser engine.</sub>
<sub>Thanks to this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/9e26f733b53dd6a9d417) for its help.</sub>